# hotkeys для копирования и вставки файлов

Tags: linux, hotkeys, xfce

У меня установлена Xubuntu 16.04.1.
Сейчас в системе для копирования и вставки файлов работает только Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V. Какие настройки сделать для того что бы копирование и вставка файлов происходила по Ctrl+Insert, Shift+Inster, и по Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V?
В настройках клавиатуры найти такие сочетания клавиш не смог.

Comment: вам продублировать нужно или вы хотите в терминал копировать по ctrl+V???

Comment: Мне нужно что бы выделив файл в любой папке и нажав `Ctrl+Insert` это файл скопировался в буфер, а нажав `Shift+Insert` он вставился в текущую папку.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках клавиатуры добавьте команду:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+C
```

для Ctrl+Insert и:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+V
```

для Shift+Insert.

Должна быть установлена программа xdotool.